# Term for something that appears complex but is actually very simple

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

The Japanese have a term for something that appears simple but is actually very complex in detail: [*Shibui*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shibui). It should be said that this is only one aspect of *Shibui*, as with many Japanese words/concepts.

Is there a term for the opposite: something that appears hopelessly complicated, but in actuality is quite simple, whether this is because it follows a subjectively unknown pattern, or because of the subjective perspective of the person?

Comment: Something as complicated as the "Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything" and as simple as "42"? ;-)

Comment: Your question looks deceptively complex :)

Comment: Something that's [*fractal*](http://www.wordnik.com/words/fractal) gains its complexity by repeating geometric patterns at increasingly smaller scales.

Comment: If you mean [渋い](http://kanjidict.stc.cx/japkanji.php?d1=on&s=しぶい&max=10&exact=on&btnJ=Search+JA→EN&d3=on&d9=on&d15=on), then I disagree with your interpretation. The Wikipedia entry you cite is a Western interpretation of the term, which applies Western frosting to what is essentially a Japanese idea. Things that are *shibui* really are simple, not complicated. They have nuances, but that does not make them complicated. There isn't enough room in this comment to elaborate, but you would do well to acquaint yourself with the culture that produced this term before generalizing.

Comment: @Robusto初夢 Thanks for the clarification; I never meant to offend with an incomplete transliteration; in fact, I never assumed I could fully translate/understand the term itself.  I will not even try now.  I apologize for the offense, and I'll try to refrain from committing it again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In OP's context, everything is either *simple* or *complex*, **and** for any given thing, either it's obvious which applies, or the appearance is deceptive.

Things that both appear to be, and really are, simple are hardly worth mentioning. Nor is it normally worth saying that something which appears complex really *is* complex. So the only cases worth mentioning are things that look simple but are actually complex, and things that look complex but are actually simple.

As others have noted, the first case is often called *deceptively simple*. We often admire things which are superficially simple, but which we know are actually complex, so it's effectively a complimentary expression - which once given is often followed by an explanation/discussion of the "hidden" complexity.

But we don't admire complexity for it's own sake - quite the reverse, in fact. If you're giving a value judgement on something meeting that criterion, you'd probably say something more scathing than *deceptively complex* - which barely exists [by comparison with the "standard" version](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=deceptively%20simple,deceptively%20complex&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) (I think people avoid the inversion partly because it might be misconstrued as a compliment).

In practice the context where we need to say something is simpler than it appears is often when we're speaking to someone else who is confused by the superficial complexity. In which case we reassure them by saying something like **"It's easy, really"**. And then proceed to explain it.

Just because there are four positions in the "truth table" under discussion, doesn't mean we need a "matching set" of four names. Two are just trivial. The other two normally arise in different contexts (though in both cases it's likely you'll carry on by actually explaining whatever it is).

EDIT: The nearest "real-world" antonym I can think of to something that's *deceptively simple* is [emergent complexity](http://www.ridgenet.net/~do_while/sage/v10i6f.htm), a term often used of systems wherein a small number of simple elements are repeatedly recombined to create something complex. Particle physics, fractal designs, or living organisms, for example.

Comment: This answer is *deceptively complex* in that it is long and complicated yet says nothing. That's a lot of hand waving to say, "I don't know a word/phrase for the concept, and thus there must be no answer."

Comment: @David Harkness: Rubbish. I'm saying there is no standard term, because *we don't need it*. Lanuguage is not symmetrical.

Comment: I agree that there is no intrinsic need to name every concept in language, but that doesn't mean there isn't a word for this particular concept. I was just surprised that the OP accepted your "I don't know a word for this so there must be none" answer after only 3 hours. :)

Comment: @David Harkness: I'm not saying *there is no word/term*. Of course we can all express such a straightforward concept. I'm simply saying there won't be anything that particularly functions as an "antonym" for *deceptively simple*, because the real-world contexts for using it are not "mirrors" of the original. Reassuring composite phrases using *actually* or *really* are far more likely.

Answer (score 18):

We call a thing which is actually simple but appears complex *deceptively complex*. Both [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/deceptive) and [CALD](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/deceptive) call something which is actually complex but appears simple *deceptively simple*.

Comment: @BenCole: note that phrases using *deceptively* are prone to misinterpretation. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25013/how-should-deceptively-actually-be-used

Comment: I've upvoted this because if OP really needs a term, it's the best available - though I'm a bit irked that my answer *"we don't normally need to reference this concept"* has attracted nothing but downvotes. And I can't resist pointing out that Google books records just 7 instances of "*it's deceptively complex*" (all within the last decade or so), as against a couple of thousand for "*it's deceptively simple*". We really don't need this term, and often all it will do is confuse people.

Comment: @Peter Shor: I think you're probably right - it seems to me *most* instances of ["deceptively dangerous"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22deceptively+dangerous%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), for example, don't mean *looks dangerous, but actually isn't*. They mostly mean *looks harmless, but is actually dangerous*. Logically speaking I suppose for something that's already been identified as *deceptive*, there's no particular reason why the specified attribute should be the the appearance or the reality, so neither choice is inherently "erroneous".

Answer (score 3):

The only term that comes immediately to my mind is "deceptively simple".

As an example, if I ask you to tell me the area of a triangle with sides 4, 7, and 11, you might go and dig up  [Heron's Formula](http://www.clarku.edu/~djoyce/trig/area.html) (area=sqrt(s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)), where s=(a+b+c)/2) and start calculating it, or you might notice that side a + side b = side c, and thus the "triangle" is actually 2 straight lines, and therefore the area must be 0.

Comment: Doesn't deceptively simple mean just the opposite - seems simple, but actually isn't?

Comment: @onomatomaniak I concur; _deceptively simple_ actually captures _shibui_ quite well.

Comment: I agree with @hellion, I've always heard and used "deceptively *simple*" used this way - for something appearing complex but actually being simple.

Comment: By definition, any simplicity is *deceptive*, as it's merely masking the difficulty.

Comment: The usage examples [here](http://www.wordnik.com/words/deceptively%20simple) describe things that are simple on the surface, but actually not.

Comment: I think I agree with Hellion in that if a thing is simple, and it deceives in regards to its simplicity, then it is deceptively simple. But everyone should read [this language log post about the word deceptive](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3500) and then note that it seems many writers use deceptively simple to mean the opposite of what this answer says.

Comment: -1: Having just leafed through the first dozen or so contextualised instances of ["it's deceptively simple"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22it%27s+deceptively+simple%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in Google Books, I didn't find a single one with this "inverted" meaning. They were all for things that *look superficially simple, but are actually complex*. OP asks for a term applicable to things that *look superficially complex, but are actually simple*.

Answer (score 3):

A '[ruse](http://www.wordnik.com/words/ruse)' is meant to deceive, to hide the truth, possibly by making something appear more complex than it is. Ruse *does not* explicitly relate to complexity vs. simplicity, but it does relate to the subjective perspective of the person: they are being deceived by a trick that can easily be exposed, thus revealing the truth. And truth is often simpler than deception.

Answer (score 1):

"Something that appears hopelessly complicated, but in actuality is quite simple" might be called a *[Gordian knot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordian_knot)*, of which wikipedia says,

> The Gordian Knot is a legend of Phrygian Gordium associated with Alexander the Great. It is often used as a metaphor for an intractable problem solved easily by cheating or "thinking outside the box" ("cutting the Gordian knot")

Note, this answer was suggested by answers to a [related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59693), which apparently seeks the four-word phrase that the wikipedia quote shows in parentheses, or perhaps "thinking outside the box", or perhaps something else entirely.