# Phrase for a problem that seems impossible, but actually has a simple and obvious solution?

Tags: phrase-requests

Daniel M. Russell poses what he claims is a deceptively simple brain teaser in his [blog](http://searchresearch1.blogspot.com.au/2012/02/wednesday-search-challenge-22912.html):

> What short 4-word idiomatic phrase (in English) captures [the] idea of
>   a problem that seems impossible, but actually has a simple and obvious
>   solution?

"Deceptively simple brain teaser" is the best I could come up with, but I don't think it's particularly idiomatic.

*UPDATE*:

So, the originating blogger has posted his [intended answer](http://searchresearch1.blogspot.com.au/2012/03/answer-impossible-yet-simple.html). I would agree that there was no stand-out candidate amongst all the plausible suggestions, so kudos to all those who found a solution.

Comment: What's wrong with the "Keep It Simple, Stupid (KISS)" suggested in a comment on that blog post?

Comment: @Jim: I reckon KISS is advice on how to tackle problems, rather than a phrase that describes a type of problem.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what Russell is saying there - he's posing a "riddle" to which the *answer* is [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) (Keep it simple, Stupid!), but unless you're already familiar with the answer it's neither simple nor obvious.

Comment: In fact, probably the appropriate answer here actually *is* "riddle". Which in certain contexts can mean a superficially complex question where the answer is obvious once you get to it. But I don't think English really has a dedicated word for this sort of thing - if it did, that word would turn up repeatedly in the context of cryptic crossword puzzles, which usually have exactly that characteristic.

Comment: "Elemental, My Dear Watson", is what came to my mind first, when he said, that the solution is trivial once revealed:)

Comment: It's "Elementary, my dear Watson." The phrase is oft-quoted, yet never actually appeared in any of the Holmes stories by Conan Doyle.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Term for something that appears complex but is actually very simple](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51804/term-for-something-that-appears-complex-but-is-actually-very-simple)

Comment: @Mitch: It's not a precise duplicate, but rather a more specific request (i.e. describes a problem, must be four words).

Comment: @JimmyX: Precisely so, JimmyX. "Elementary, my dear Watson" became oft-quoted because it was uttered more than once by the actor Basil Rathbone in his film adaptations of Holmes.

Comment: I'd like to find out what the real answer is! @JimmyX, embarassing mistake...:) Can't edit it!

Comment: Right, not exactly a duplicate but very much related. Your particular question is very localized to requiring exactly four _words_ for this one guys blog posting  (I thought the answer would be 'ruse' or 'KISS' but those are four _letters_). So really it could be anything that the blog poster want it to be., because all the four-word suggestions so far fit fine.

Comment: "It's easy, actually," but I doubt if we can call this an idiom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the comments on that blog suggests "An egg of Columbus".   From the description here, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egg_of_Columbus, it certainly seems to fit the bill.

Comment: This is the actual solution. http://searchresearch1.blogspot.com.au/2012/03/answer-impossible-yet-simple.html

Comment: Except that it's not at all obvious (as in self-evident), nor - given that it requires explanation of the anecdote in order to make any sense - at all simple.

Answer (score 2):

It's to "cut the Gordian knot."

Comment: I like this answer, but I'm not sure it is retrospectively obvious.

Comment: How obvious it is definitely depends on the cultural baggage you carry.

Answer (score 2):

How about

> Elementary, my dear Watson

Of course this was never uttered by Holmes in any of Doyle's published works.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the riddle's answer is quite as likely to be "[thinking outside the box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thinking_outside_the_box), " as it is to be "cutting the [Gordian knot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordian_knot)".

Answer (score 0):

The Egg of Columbus

"Cutting the Gordian Knot" is to redefine the original problem to make it easy to solve.  The Gordian Knot was one which had both ends of the string deeply embedded within the knot so it was near impossible to unravel.  Someone (a greek/roman hero IIRC) just cut through it with his sword instead.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Thank you for your contribution, but *the Egg of Columbus* was already suggested, with a full explanation. Your second suggestion is a good one, but might be strengthened if you could provide a reference or external link. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help], as our site is more particular about such things than most discussion forums or Q&A sites are.