# A word that means an undeniable statement, stated emphatically

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

I'm looking for a word that means an emphatic, definitely correct, powerful assertion, kind of like "undeniable" except that doesn't capture the action aspect of making a statement. (A thesaurus didn't help).

Things that almost work and why:

1. Proclamation - it gets the loud announcement aspect but misses the factual and undeniable aspects. One can make an incorrect proclamation.
2. Axiom - An axiom is certainly accurate and provable but axiom gives no indication of the method of delivery.
3. Apodictic - it gets the clearly established and beyond dispute but again misses the emphatic delivery aspect

Contextual examples:

1. to describe the act of yelling "the building is on fire" to twenty people who are standing nearby and somehow haven't noticed fifteen-meter flames coming out the windows. "Bob was kind enough to make the _____ that the building was on fire."
2. When someone has a banana in their ear and they can't hear you say "you have a banana in your ear!" you've stated a _____.

---

In response to close vote as discussed in comments below: "..undeniability (stating the obvious) is only a part of the idea to be conveyed. In my example of the fire, no one knew the building was burning so though it was obvious, no one noticed. The question you link to [as duplicate] requests something that describes telling a fact everyone already knows.."

Comment: **Axiomatic** might work here. Not sure about the capture of action- perhaps **proclamation** is better?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Proclamation is very close but too much like an announcement.

Comment: For example: to describe the act of yelling "the building is on fire" to twenty people who are standing nearby and somehow haven't noticed 15 meter flames coming out the windows.

Comment: *That* I would call 'Stating the Bleedin' Obvious', An idiom derived from a quote from Fawlty Towers (classic British sitcom starring John Cleese). See for example http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Stating_the_bleedin'_obvious

Comment: @Avon Stating the Bleedin' Obvious captures the feeling of apparency for sure. Unfortunately, there may not exist a single word that fully gets that combined with gusto of delivery.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Word for "stating the obvious?"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11087/word-for-stating-the-obvious)

Comment: @TusharRaj undeniability (stating the obvious) is only a part of the idea to be conveyed. In my example of the fire, no one knew the building was burning so though it was obvious, no one noticed. The question you link to requests something that describes telling a fact everyone already knows. I accepted "patent" because it captures most of what I want though it still doesn't get the "delivery with umph" aspect. I think what I'm looking for doesn't exist.

Comment: My closevote was based on your previous comment. Stating the obvious and stating a universal truth are entirely different things. You should make up your mind before posting. And you should maybe wait a couple days before accepting. You have changed your accept from `axiom` to `patent`; none of which match the urgency level of my `dictum`; which I had to delete because your edit made it obsolete and it began to attract downvotes. Bottom line: post a clear question with solid examples, and don't accept too hastily if you aren't sure.

Comment: @TusharRaj point taken

Comment: I find *emphatically undeniable statement* to be an apparently meaningless group of words. The OP selected an adjective as the best equivalent of a noun phrase. How is a statement a ... patent? An emphatically undeniable statement would be contrasted with a, what, mildly undeniable one? I am moving to close as unclear.

Comment: @JimReynolds how about undeniable statement, stated emphatically?

Comment: Well, you'd like word that means a statement, so it would be a noun, right? And you want such a word to denote a certain kind of statement: one that cannot be denied, and that is made with force and clarity? I submit that I'd be very surprised if there was such a word. Moreover, I guess that you could benefit from a discussion in which people might help you develop your question. I suppose you might find help for that in the chat room. I don't frequent the EL&U chat room, but you may also or instead consider the one associated with English Language Learners.

Comment: Note that the example *The consultant's patent incompetence was somehow overlooked by management,* arguably can be denied: *No, the consultant is not incompetent.* It's not that I don't want you to be able to ask a question if you have one, but get help formulating it if you aren't sure what it is, or how to ask it. :-)

Comment: @JimReynolds So are you suggesting get help developing the question and fix this one or get help, delete this and start over? (I found one that suffered similarly http://english.stackexchange.com/q/59998/61765  See Martha's comment)

Comment: Tony: I don't know, but I'd be happy to discuss it with you. The best way is to find me in http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22937/ells-cabin (and if I'm not there, the others who most often lurk there would, I am rather sure, do their best to help you think), or email me (see my profile).

Comment: @JimReynolds Per discussion on EL&U question has been edited

Comment: It's been my observation that humans can deny anything.  And politicians can deny even more than that.

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for **"axiom"**, a statement that is regarded as being established, accepted, or self-evidently true.

> - **axiom** (noun) A self-evident or universally recognized truth; a maxim "It is an economic axiom as old as the hills that goods and services can be paid for only with goods and services" (Albert Jay Nock). [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/axiom)
> - axiomatic (adj)  relating to or resembling an axiom; self-evident

Comment: What makes an axiom emphatic or powerful?

Comment: Agreed, axiom very well captures the technical definition but misses the emotion.

Comment: Emphasis *is* achieved by tone or punctuation! Or even better, content.

Answer (score 5):

Indubitable may work for you. A statement that is indisputable, and beyond any doubt.

Comment: Indubitable is almost sarcastically understated. Not what I was looking for but I like it and may try to force it in if I can't capture the idea in one word.

Comment: Bravo, good answer. There's a custom on this site to give references from recognised sources and to add the attribution.  The first is to avoid unsubstantiated opinions, The second to comply with the law.  Is that reasonable?

Answer (score 4):

Incontrovertible maybe?, like it can't be proven wrong.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Undeniably good answer to the question. Please choose and quote sound sources for your definitions, and then (for legal reasons) attribute them.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a Greek-derived term from philosophy would provide the "umph" you're looking for? An **apodictic** proposition is "1. Incontrovertible; demonstrably true or certain." ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apodictic))
If you must have a noun, **apodict** is the form, though it must be quite rare.
(see also the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apodicticity) article)

Comment: I really like apodictic but went with patent because it's more mainstream. +1

Answer (score 2):

**[Patent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/patent)**, in one of its lesser-used meanings:

> readily visible or intelligible :  obvious

Example: "The consultant's patent incompetence was somehow overlooked by management."

The person who makes a *patent* statement might be sarcastically called [Captain Obvious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Obvious).

Answer (score 1):

affirmation

> > noun
> >     1.the action or process of affirming something or being affirmed. "he nodded in affirmation"
>
> - synonyms:  declaration, statement, assertion, proclamation,    pronouncement, attestation

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be hard to do it in one word.  I suggest

**blatant truism**

Answer (score -1):

"Bloom's Taxonomy of Learning": A concept which sums up the whole process of teaching/learning. As is so often said, "In teaching we learn."
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom%27s_taxonomy

Comment: Hello, jerry, and welcome to English Language & Usage. "Bloom's Taxonomy of Learning" is an interesting and (according to the Wikipedia article) influential framework for analyzing how people learn, but I don't see how it relate to the poster's question, which is a request for "a word that means an undeniable statement, stated emphatically." Please consider expanding your answer to clarify how the reference to Bloom's taxonomy provides (or helps provide) an answer to the poster's question. Thanks.