# Is there a term for something that is "beyond believable"?

Tags: single-word-requests

"Extra believable" might be another way to phrase what I am trying to find.

I feel like "unbelievable" is a term that is often paired with incredulity, whereas if something is believable, it is a very temppered response. Is there a term that goes past that into overwhelming certainty?

In fact, "certain" or "obvious" might be good candidates, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure why ***certain*** or ***obvious*** aren't "adequate" for your purpose. But if you're specifically looking for idiomatic expressions including ***beyond***, I'd have to say it's ***beyond question*** that ***beyond doubt*** is a good candidate. Though ***doubtless*** someone will point out that the associations of all such terms inevitably become "watered down" by overuse and hyperbole once they achieve widespread adoption.

Comment: If I believe that something is true, I do not need any exaggerated statement. I just say that it is true.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include an example sentence demonstrating how the word would be used, as [single-word-request] requires.

Comment: [This](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/256593/a-word-that-means-an-undeniable-statement-stated-emphatically/256595#256595) is close enough to generate an argument over duplication. Though one needs to switch to 'axiomatic' from 'axiom', etc.

Answer (score 2):

> **incontrovertible** *adj.*
>   Impossible to dispute; unquestionable: *incontrovertible proof of the defendant's innocence.*
>   [--freedictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/incontrovertible)

*Contravertible* here means *convince-able* or *contradict-able*, prefixing *in* (not) to that means "*cannot be contradicted*", marking something that it would be illogical or unreasonable to deny, as with a satisfactory mathematical proof.

If we regard logical proofs as objects, which exist independent of human opinion or belief, then proofs which 
are *incontrovertible* are literately above and beyond belief.

---

A more obscure *Greek* import meaning "*demonstrated*" has similar intent, but it's only used by academic philosophers:

> [**apodictic**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/apodictic) (*adj*)   Clearly established or beyond dispute.

Answer (score 1):

You may be thinking of *[undeniable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/undeniable#English)*:

> #### undeniable (adj)
>
> [irrefutable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/irrefutable#English), or impossible to deny

Other synonyms or near synonyms include *[unquestionable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unquestionable#English)* and *[indisputable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/indisputable#English)*.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I'm unable to disagree with @FumbleFingers' comment, I am conscious that you have asked, not about "belief" but "believability" - which are not entirely the same thing. That may explain why you are not able to accept "certain" or "obvious".

In circumstances where you cannot be "certain", or "believe beyond doubt", you might say that "the suspect's story is "***eminently believable***".

It doesn't mean you are sure. It doesn't even mean that you believe he/she is telling the truth, but simply that the statement has a strong element of **believability** about it.

Answer (score 0):

Utterly convincing. Carrying complete conviction.