# word to describe a complex/multi-dimensional question which can't be pithily answered

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for the word to use in the following situation - suppose one is asked a grand question that could form the basis for a mini research project in a way that almost suggests it has a simple, one-word, one-number sort of answer. The response from the one being asked would be "that's a very [insert word here] question" - unfortunately the only thing which comes to mind is "loaded" but that is not correct, and has its own meaning.

Comment: "That's a very **interesting** question" is what I hear: It implies that its complexity interests the speaker and would also interest others. For example, *A: "He was found in the same locked room as the body of his enemy and the gun had been fired recently by him. He did it, didn't he?" B: "That's a very interesting question... but there are a few other possibilities."*

Comment: I hear *deceptive*.

Comment: You have complex and multi-dimensional already. What’s wrong with them?

Comment: See [Something simple and yet complex…](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76906/something-simple-and-yet-complex).

Comment: 'Deceptively complex' fits well unless one insists on a single word. // Related: [Idiom for something that appears to be easy but is in fact hard](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/389477/idiom-for-something-that-appears-to-be-easy-but-is-in-fact-hard).

Answer (score 0):

If the word you seek is intended to indicate that the questioner is deliberately implying that the question has a simple answer, whilst knowing that the answer is complex, you could say that the question is **disingenuous**.  See, for example, [Merriam-Webster's definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disingenuous):

> Disingenuous: lacking in candor
>
> also : giving a false appearance of simple frankness