# Complex yet not, something that can be explained in a different, simpler way

Tags: single-word-requests

Here's the sentence I need to complete :
A religious speaks of angels bringing us from heaven before we birth, someone says they don't believe this because they aren't religious, so I explain that I think it's more of a ______
The word "reference" could be used but that's not really what I'm looking for.

Comment: I would like to offer an edit, but I don't want to change your intended meaning. " *A **religion** speaks of angels bringing us from heaven before we **are born**. Some says, 'I don't believe this because I am not religious.' But I explain to them that I think it's more of a ______.*" Does that match your original statement?

Comment: It would appear from the English mistakes in the sentence you quote that your question is not appropriate to this site, but to English Language Learners. If you had completed the tutorial and read the help before posting this would have been clear to you.

Answer (score 1):

> **Allegory**
> [al-uh-gawr-ee, -gohr-ee]
> noun, plural allegories.
>
> 1. a representation of an abstract or spiritual meaning through concrete or material forms; figurative treatment of one subject under the guise of another.
> 2. a symbolical narrative.
>
> [Source: Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/allegory)

"...I think it's more of an allegory"

or

"...I think it's more allegorical than literal."

Answer (score 0):

Although I think PV22's answer is rather sufficient, there is an interesting discussion over a similar question here: [Term for something that appears complex but is actually very simple](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51804/term-for-something-that-appears-complex-but-is-actually-very-simple)

Comment: this is better posted as a comment