# Is there a word for a person who looks absent-minded, but in fact notices everything carefully?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm coming out from the word [absent-mindedness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absent-mindedness):

> Absent-mindedness is where a person shows inattentive or forgetful behaviour. It can have three different causes:
>
> - a low level of attention ("blanking" or "zoning out")
> - intense attention to a single object of focus (hyperfocus) that makes a person oblivious to events around him or her;

I'm wondering whether there is a word for a person who only looks to behave like this, but in fact listens to everything around them.

I do this a lot. Whenever I'm in a group of people, I either look like I'm zoned-out thinking about my work stuff, or listening to only one person, but in fact I'm carefully taking in everything other people are speaking.

Another good example would be the character [Columbo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Columbo) from the show of the same name. He always looked like he was ignoring everyone, totally absent-minded, while in fact he was doing this on purpose to keep his suspects from being too careful around him.

What is the word for such a person?

Comment: Columbo is pretty famous so maybe 'a Columbo'?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - I tried watching Colombo a couple of days ago. It's unbelievably slow. There's like 10 minutes worth of plot in each episode; the rest is fluff, fluff, and more fluff. It was kind of awkward - I felt sorry for the actors.

Comment: @Ricky: that's very subjective I'd say. I love the show, every episode of it. The behavior of Columbo is one of the main elements of the show, so the episodes are not supposed to be purely plot, but mainly the 'fluff' you obviously don't like.

Comment: I've never watched it. However I still know the meme. That's why I suggested it.

Comment: @Ricky: what episode was this exactly?

Comment: @RiMMER: must have been the one where they had an old dot matrix printer...  Disclaimer: I like Columbo.

Comment: @RiMMER - I believe Minnow is right. Dot matrix and all. I mean, I realize there are only four commercial breaks, and they had all those minutes in between to fill in somehow, but that scene was just insulting.

Comment: Feign: To give a false appearance of:

Comment: I suspect that the only concise term for the concept is to refer to a person or fictional character with the trait, and I must say that Columbo is probably the most familiar reference, at least in the US.

Comment: @Ricky - I remember that episode, and I recall that it was one of the more tedious ones.  There was a significant variation over the 13 seasons the show was produced, presumably due to different writers, etc.

Comment: @HotLicks: The thing about sustaining an acceptable dramatic level for more than three episodes using the same characters is - you can't. There are no brilliant long-running shows; art isn't an assembly line. That said, some professionalism is most certainly in order. If a writer can't write enough dialogue to sustain the viewer's interest throughout an episode, he should be replaced. Showing me closeups of thoughtful faces, cars driving on a highway, birdies singing ditties, etc, doesn't cut it. At least not anymore: the advent of cable an the Internet has exposed the hacks and frauds ...

Comment: @HotLicks ... of television. One episode per week was a boon for them. Now when you can watch three commercial-free episodes in a row, you see them for what they are: fluff. That's also why movies are becoming less and less popular: you can't make hundreds of intriguing movies each year: most are filled with tedious fluff and are an ignominious waste of time.

Comment: @Ricky - The only way to watch them commercial-free is on DVD or Netflix -- on cable or open air reruns they have more commercials than ever.

Comment: @Hotlicks: Yes, and so I have. The results are before us.

Answer (score 4):

> Playing dumb

Based on your description this seems to encompass the sentiment.

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/play+dumb

Alternatively:

> Deceptively absent-minded

Comment: Anyone can play dumb. It's not a character trait. By the way, I didn't downvote you: I don't downvote: I leave that kind of thing to people who are fond of that kind of thing.

Comment: Well I *do* downvote.  But I upvoted this one.

Answer (score 2):

Idiot-savant comes to mind, but that's neither accurate nor indeed specific enough. I've looked up some synonyms: no cigar. The problem with defining such people is there's more to their patterns of behavior than meets the eye. They're whimsical. One never knows when they're:

1. Pretending to be absentminded to throw everybody off
2. Pretending to be absentminded because they're bored with what the others are discussing or doing
3. Being genuinely absentminded
4. Pretending to be absentminded because they don't know how to answer a question
5. Pretending to be absentminded just to spite everybody

   - and so forth.

Also, you never know how much of it is deliberate, and how much instinctive. Like that sleepy Texas sheriff. You know:

He's parked behind a tree, with the radar pointed in the right direction. He's dozing off. Cars keep zooming by on the highway. He couldn't care less. A whole bunch of cars rolls by, all of them most definitely over the speed limit. 80 mph. 85. 90. 85 again. 80. 92. 93. 85. And so forth. Nothing: no reaction from the sheriff. All of a sudden this souped-up Porsche flies by, doing 140! The sheriff opens one eye, looks at the radar, and goes, "Wow, I'll be f***!" The next moment, the engine is running, the lights and siren are on, and he swings onto the highway in pursuit of the offending Porsche.

He wasn't *pretending* to be absentminded. He was actually being absentminded. Which didn't stop him from acting quickly when it became really necessary to do his duty.
Something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could say "[deceptively](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/deceptive) attentive."

Comment: I was going to suggest *deceptively **alert*** but since that's so close to yours, I'll just leave it as a comment.

Comment: Wouldn't it be *deceptively inattentive*?

Comment: Nope.  The person is actually attentive.  He deceives you into thinking he's not.  So he's deceptively attentive.

Comment: Deceptively attentive or alert should be used for someone who appears wide awake in a meeting, but is actually daydreaming.

Comment: The right use of "deceptively" is actually really weird. It's one of those words where you think it's easy, and then you think about it and realize it can be taken both ways. (It's deceptively easy!) http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25013/how-should-deceptively-actually-be-used

Comment: I understand how the phrase could cause confusion, but when I break it down, I can't see it the other way.  If something is "surprisingly good," it's good, just in a surprising way.  If somebody is "devilishly handsome," they're handsome, just in a devilish way.   So to me if someone is deceptively attentive, they'd be attentive, just in a deceptive way.  I'd like to hear an example that would make me rethink it.

Answer (score 1):

***Poker face***

Poker face, from Merriam Webster: "An expression on your face that does not show your thoughts or feelings; an inscrutable face that reveals no hint of a person's thoughts or feelings."

Poker face, from the Urban Dictionary: "A face on a person that shows no emotion, often called poker face because in the game of poker it would be foolish to show any emotional traits that might screw the game for you."

Sentence:  "Don't let his poker face fool you; he absorbs everything, and a day later he might analyze the entire discussion."

Another Sentence:  "Hey, poker face! What are you thinking?"

Comment: Wouldn't a poker face have a totally different connotation, though? A poker face is put on _because_ someone is super-focused on the game at hand--they're hiding their emotions on purpose as part of their strategy. The question is asking for a word to describe that guy who looks like he's drifted off to a different planet and has no idea what game is even being played--but is actually very mentally "present".

Comment: The term can be, and is, adopted for the guy who looks mentally absent but is mentally present, even if it is not part of his strategy.

Answer (score -1):

You are only *superficially inattentive*.

> [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/superficial):
>
> **superficial**
>
> 2b :  seen on the surface :  external
>
> 2c :  presenting only an appearance without substance or significance