# International English - Question related to an adjective used to describe a very easy to grasp, yet thoroughly complex concept

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, vocabulary

I'm looking for a word that would describe a certain idea that is so easy-to-grasp that it appears to be innate, yet it is thoroughly complex and complicated.

An example is national identity, which anyone can understand and explain in simple terms, but there are extensive bodies of literature and research on the subject.

Comment: I would say "deceptive".

Comment: I think _deceptively simple_ may work here.

Answer (score -1):

To echo comments, how about **Deceptively Complex**?

Comment: I'd warn against this: _deceptively_ is used frequently with the opposite meaning. See here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25013/how-should-deceptively-actually-be-used

Comment: Yep, **deceptively complex** would be more appropriate.