# A word for something that is deeper, more compelling than what is obvious or visible

Tags: meaning, nuance

Is there a word to describe the quality of something that is deeper, more substantial, or more compelling than what is obvious or originally thought?

I am thinking of something abstract, like a thought or something philosophical like Ursula K. Le Guin's definition of communication.

Comment: Something "unexpectedly complex" would warrant deeper thought...not necessarily making it compelling, but perhaps leading to other considerations worthy of more attention.

Comment: 'Deceptively profound' -- not obviously, but *deceptively* profound. It sounds simple but has layers of complex meaning.

Comment: I like the word **rich** here, which if necessary could be combined with "surprisingly" or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

(Deceptively) **profound** -- not obviously, but deceptively profound. It sounds simple but has layers of complex meaning.

> Profound *adjective* (of a person or statement) having or showing great knowledge or insight.

Source: [dictionary definition at google search](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=profound&oq=profound&aqs=chrome..69i57.3043j0j4&client=tablet-android-samsung&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8)

Also read: ['deceptively' usage -- an earlier question and answers here at English.StackExchange.com]
[How should "deceptively" actually be used?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25013/how-should-deceptively-actually-be-used)

> Example (mine) Professor B's lecture on the 'interconnectedness of experience' was *deceptively profound.*

Other examples: [google search results for the exact phrase "deceptively profound"](https://www.google.co.in/search?client=tablet-android-samsung&ei=0TFjWbrNFYLbvgSu85-YAQ&q="deceptively+profound"&oq="deceptively+profound"&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3...3155.6397.0.8514.3.3.0.0.0.0.290.499.2-2.2.0....0...1.1j4.64.mobile-gws-serp..1.0.0.8OJ-SbNXD08)

Option 2: *understated wisdom*.